# Clip not rendering?

Tags: flash

I've run into a weird problem.

Frame 1 contains a small preloader, and when its done, it jumps to frame 2. 
Frame 2 contains the main clip, *website*, which contains several other clips, two of them are called *menu* and *logo*.
*logo* contains a dynamic textfield, and thats it. 
*menu* contains a clip with a dynamic textfield in it, and the clip is duplicated by actionscript at runtime.

When I run my movie within the Flash IDE (Ctrl+Enter) everything is fine. 
If i choose Simulate Download, a strange thing happens.

The clip *website* is not displayed at all. 
The _root frame is 2, but any clip in that frame is not displayed, including *website*.

I've tried deleting some clips to locate the problem. I found out that if I delete *menu* AND *logo* in the *website* clip the problem goes away. If i just delete one of them, the problem remains.

I tried moving the clips around, putting them in container clips, put nothing helps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started over, and then it worked. 
Wasn't able to figure out the difference....